# QuantLib linker error: QuantLib::Error::Error()

Tags: c++, linker, quantlib

I am trying to get QL working on Debian, but failing at the last step. I have downloaded the source, built and installed the library (“make”, “make install”) without any errors, but my application that uses the QuantLib library throws up some linker errors related to a single class (QuantLib::Error):

```
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/PricingEngine.o: In function `QuantLib::Observable::notifyObservers()':
/usr/local/include/ql/patterns/observable.hpp:143: undefined reference to `QuantLib::Error::Error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'

build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/PricingEngine.o: In function `QuantLib::operator+(QuantLib::Array const&, QuantLib::Array const&)':
/usr/local/include/ql/math/array.hpp:499: undefined reference to `QuantLib::Error::Error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'

build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/PricingEngine.o: In function `QuantLib::DiscretizedOption::reset(unsigned long)':
/usr/local/include/ql/discretizedasset.hpp:222: undefined reference to `QuantLib::Error::Error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'

build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/PricingEngine.o: In function `QuantLib::Instrument::setupArguments(QuantLib::PricingEngine::arguments*) const':
/usr/local/include/ql/instrument.hpp:145: undefined reference to `QuantLib::Error::Error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'

build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/PricingEngine.o: In function `QuantLib::Instrument::performCalculations() const':
/usr/local/include/ql/instrument.hpp:164: undefined reference to `QuantLib::Error::Error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'

build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/PricingEngine.o:/usr/local/include/ql/instrument.hpp:176: more undefined references to `QuantLib::Error::Error(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, long, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)' follow
```

I’m on Debian 8, amd64, compiled both the library and application with g++-5.

Does anyone have any ideas?

EDIT: Here's the command line:

```
g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/hub build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Calculations.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Client.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Connection.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/DataStore.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Hub.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Instruments.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Parameters.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/PricingEngine.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/Server.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/main.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/stdafx.o -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib ../Core/dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/libcore.a -lQuantLib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_log.a /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_log_setup.a -lboost_system -lzmq -lboost_filesystem -lpq -lboost_unit_test_framework -lboost_thread -lpgm -lldap -lssl -lcrypto -lsodium -ldl -pthread
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that `PricingEngine.o` is compiled with (default) value of `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1`, while `QuantLib` is compiled with `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0`.

See also example at the end of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32426348/50617).